# If you had only two full days to visit Venice Italy for the first time, what would you see and do?

Tags: italy, sightseeing, venice

Going with my sister (two healthy/active 60 year old women)to Venice for the first time in early September and don't really know what to expect. We will have two full days and a half day when we arrive. Where should we start? How should we plan those days? More interested in outdoor sights than in spending hours in museums or galleries. How should we make the most of our time? We will be staying very near the train station in Cannaregio.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. My recommendation is to consult a travel guide, at a minimum something like WikiVoyage's overview of Venice, then return here for refinement. The StackExchange format is best suited to questions that have a single definitive answer; sightseeing tends to be dependent on opinion because different people weigh criteria differently in their ranking (cost, convenience, location, "authenticity," etc.). I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Since I've never been to Venice, it's difficult for me to be more specific than I was in my question.  I'm also OK with opinions and suggestions and I'm OK with deciding which of them holds appeal for me since I trust that those who have experience with visiting or living in Venice would have valuable advice to share....at least advice worth considering.  I have already read some guides and articles about Venice but it's hard to visualize what it will be like being there for a short time and was hoping for some personal tips from someone who knows the city.

Comment: Take a vaporeti, the public transport ferries that go through the whole canale grande for cheap. It's better than sitting in an overpriced gondola.

Answer (score 4):

Venice is not necessarily an all indoors experience.  From your hotel, it's a brisk walk to [Piazza San Marco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piazza_San_Marco), and if you are up for a more arduous walk, check out the [Lido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lido_di_Venezia) (you'll need to take a ferry part of the way to get there). It's not too late in the season for swimming there and the beach is world class.

But most of all, September is a great time to use Venice as a base while exploring other islands in the lagoon.  [Burano](http://www.isoladiburano.it/en/index.html), for example, is favoured by locals (and me) for it's authentic restaurants (along with less touristy prices).

[Torcello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torcello) has a great open air market as does [Mazzorbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazzorbo).  Mazzorbo has an artsy-craftsy fair which will still be open, and Torcello was the one-time home of Ernest Hemingway.

All of the islands have well preserved architecture and several have ruins from the Roman era.  As an additional consideration, take note that during the high season (which encroaches into September), tourists outnumber locals by a [mind-numbing 600 to 1](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/03/30/travel/the-wonder-list-venice-bill-weir/index.html)! It makes getting away to the outskirts all that more attractive.

You can take ferries or private water taxis to any of the larger islands.

Comment: And when you're in San Marcos Square, pay the couple of euro to take the lift up the bell tower to see the view.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful tips....this is the kind of information I hoped to read.  Getting out to the islands sounds like a good idea, at least for part of one day.  And the lift to the Bell Tower in San Marcos Square...will make note of that too.  If you have any other "must dos" or "must sees" ...I will forgive you for being too "opinion based" in your answer...if you'll forgive me for being too "opinion based" in my question. :)

Comment: Yes...I should be very easy to find...I'm probably the only Mikell Herrick (Dunedin, Florida) on Facebook and my content is mostly public as well.  Thank you for the offer. :)

Comment: @MikellHerrick, check 'other'